# Eclipse RCP application Log View: change/set TimeZone for messages sent to the Eclipse Log view

Tags: eclipse, view, timezone, logging, rcp

I'm developing an RCP application that uses the Eclipse Log view.

All the messages logged have the TimeZone set to system current time.
I need to have those messages all in GMT time for example

As far as I can see, there is no direct customisation possibility regarding the emitted timestamps in the Eclipse Log view.

Subclassing of Eclipse classes etc. wouldn't help much either, since most of the things we would have to change are private fields / private methods of 'internal' classes.

Any suggestion on how I can configure the eclipse Log View plugin in my RCP application to have the time of those log messages in GMT time for instance?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set the timezone via the system property `user.timezone` and the Java class `java.util.TimeZone`.

### Example

You want to change the timezone to *GMT*:

```
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "GMT");
TimeZone.setDefault(null);
```

---

*Note 1:* `TimeZone.setDefault(null)` is required to reset the default timezone to the new value provided by `user.timezone`

*Note 2:* This will change the timezone of your JVM.