# Java System.getProperty( "user.timezone" ) does not work

Tags: java, datetime, properties, timezone, system

When I start java program by `java -Duser.timezone="UTC"`,

```
System.out.println( System.getProperty( "user.timezone" ) );
System.out.println( new Date() ); // prints time in UTC
```

prints UTC time, but when I set in code like:

```
System.setProperty( "user.timezone", "UTC" );
System.out.println( System.getProperty( "user.timezone" ) );  // prints 'UTC'
System.out.println( new Date() ); // prints time in local zone, not in UTC
```

does not print time in UTC . I need to set time in code. Not looking for Joda

Environment: JDK 1.6 / Windows XP

Please help. Thanks much!

Comment: That's your entire `main()` code?

Comment: Rather than fiddle with the VM instance settings, how about being more programmatic, using the `TimeZone` approach? `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`

Comment: They both work for me (in JDK 7).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : try calling `System.out.println( new Date() ); ` before setting the property.

Comment: @leonbloy That breaks it.

Comment: @BlackBox That's elegant, up-voted!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your problem is that earlier, at JVM startup, Java has already set the default timezone, it has called `TimeZone.setDefault(...);` using the original `"user.timezone"` property. Just changing the property  afterwards with `System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC")` has in itself no effect.

That's why the normal way to set the default timezone at start time is: `java -Duser.timezone=...`

If you insist on setting the timezone programatically, you can, after changing the property, set the default timezone to `null` to force its recalculation:

```
  System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");
  TimeZone.setDefault(null);
```

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268013/eclipse-rcp-application-log-view-change-set-timezone-for-messages-sent-to-the-e/10371301#10371301)).

Or, simpler and cleaner, set it explicity:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Be aware of potential issues if [running under a SecurityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891971/277304).